# Replace occurences of string that contains any number

Tags: ios, string

Say I have a string that contains a control code "\f3" (yes it is RTF). I want to replace that control code with another string. At the moment I am using `[mutableString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\f3" withString:@"replacement string" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [mutableString length])];`

This works fine, however sometimes the code can be "\f4" or even "\f12" for example. How do I replace these strings? I could use `replaceOccurrencesOfString` for each, but the better way to do it is using wildcards, as it could be any number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions would do it.

Take a look at [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (iOS >= 4) and [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for how regular expressions work.

You will want something like:

```
// Create your expression
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = 
  [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\b\f[0-9]*\\b"
                                            options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                              error:&error];

// Replace the matches
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string
                                                       options:0
                                                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                                                  withTemplate:@"replacement string"];
```

WARNING : I've not tested my regaular expression and I'm not that great at getting them right first time; I just know that regular expressions are the way forward for you and it has to look *something* like that ;)

Comment: Excellent! That's just what I was looking for. I thought it was something to do with regular expressions, but have always avoided them up until now! Guess I have to get learning.