# Is there something better than stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString for this task?

Tags: ios

I am using:

```
cleanedDataCellR2C2 =  [cleanedDataCellR2C2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
```

and a whole bunch of similar satements to remove all keyboard characters from a textfield,  except the digits....  - (the minus sign), + (the plus sign),  as well as 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, and 9 numbers in a text field.  The example above simply converts a comma in an `NSString` to a null value.

Hate to admit it, but in one project, I'm actually using about 80 statements -- one for every keyboard character except those shown above.  Thee must be some easier way.  What would you suggest to do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to not let them enter non-numeric data in the first place, if you can. Are you using a `UITextField`? If not, ignore the rest of this, but if so:

First, make your view controller is a `UITextFieldDelegate`, e.g.:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

and then later, in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.myTextField.delegate = self;
```

Second, add a `shouldChangeCharacterInRange` to only allow the desired characters:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSCharacterSet *nonNumeric = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-0123456789"] invertedSet];

    if ([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonNumeric].location == NSNotFound)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

Third, you might want to change your text field's keyboard to be for numeric data only, e.g. `self.myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation` or `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using regex, here are a couple of examples:

[Use regular expression to find/replace substring in NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661690/user-regular-expression-to-find-replace-substring-in-nsstring)

[NSRegularExpression: Replace url text with <a> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903608/nsregularexpression-replace-url-text-with-a-tags)

[Replace occurences of string that contains any number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149775/replace-occurences-of-string-that-contains-any-number)

You can also check out http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/